# I want to list all the subfolder inside a container using azure storage api

Tags: rest, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have a hierarchy

```
my container
  --images
      --img01
      --img02
```

I want to make a rest request and get the result: `<BlobPrefix>images</BlobPrefix>`

As shown at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/enumerating-blob-resources under the section "Delimited Blob List"

But, I am not getting this result instead of i am getting all the resources names as a recursive calls. As though I am not supplying any delimiter.

String to Sign is:

```
GET /account/mycontainer

x-ms-date:Tue, 07 Feb 2017 05:38:21 GMT
x-ms-version:2016-05-31
comp:list
delimeter:/
maxresults:4
restype:container
```

URL I am sending:

```
http://account.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list&delimeter=/&maxresults=4
```

In result I am getting:

```
<xml>
<blobs>
<blob><Name>images/img01</Name>
<blob><Name>images/img02</Name>
</blobs>
</xml>
```

However based on above mentioned link. The response should be:

```
<xml>
<blobs>
<BlobPrefix>
<Name>images/</Name>
</BlobPrefix >
</xml>
```

Comment: the response returned is correct. The folders are just logical in case of blob storage. Storage account > container > blob  is the structure in which the blobs are stored. delimiting by  \ gives a folder like logical separation but it is all part of the blob. The blob uri alone is unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to your description, I checked [Delimited Blob List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/enumerating-blob-resources) and tested this method on my side. To simplify this issue, I created a container and set "Container Public Access Level" to "Public read access for container and blobs". Here is the file structure of my blob container:

[image]

- **List blobs without specifying the delimeter ('/' by default)**

https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/brucechen?restype=container&comp=list

**Result:**

[image]

- **List blobs by specifying the delimeter ('/' by default)**

https://brucechen.blob.core.windows.net/brucechen?restype=container&comp=list&delimiter=%2F

**Result:**

[image]

According to your `stringToSign`, the name of `delimeter` is incorrect, you need to change it to `delimiter`. For more details, you could refer to [List Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/list-blobs).

Comment: Bro, thanks. It was a huge mistake and I new its related to that but just can't believe it.